# How to Call Procedures in Functions from Another Database in Azure Elastic

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I had all my stuff set up nicely on a local SQL Server install.
I have on Database that holds all the generic stored procedures and functions, and the other databases would call them and pass in the variables as needed.  Everything worked great and I didn't need to copy a dozen tables and sprocs/functions into every single database I worked in.

Work made me move to Azure and right now I hate it.  I can no longer do this.  I have figured out how to add an external source to a database, but I'm back to creating a dozen tables in every database.  While they may not be physical tables, the work is nearly the same.

I can't figure out how to call my sprocs and functions though.

A good example is this one.
`[UL].[dbo].[fn_LocationInfo](0,'ROMEO','MI','48065','')`

The function [fn_LocationInfo] lives in the [UL] database, and uses the [CityStateInfo] table in [UL].  I need to call it from the [IZ] database and right now I'm getting:
`"Reference to database and/or server name in 'UL.dbo.fn_LocationInfo' is not supported in this version of SQL Server."`

Help!

Comment: So it sounds like you might have some reorging to do lol Seriously though, you have options. You can restructure your multiple database design to use schemas instead. solves your problem but might not be ideal. You could figure out how to use azure data factory, logic apps, automation accounts or azure functions to try and piece it together but itll probably be a bit gross. You could use python (or some other language) to try and hit logic apps html end points, but that means youre stepping outside of sql server (which could be a good thing though?)

Answer (score 0):

Use [sp_execute_remote](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-execute-remote-azure-sql-database?view=azuresqldb-current) which "Executes a Transact-SQL statement on a single remote Azure SQL Database or set of databases serving as shards in a horizontal partitioning scheme.".

But with so much cross-database querying you might want to either:

1. Consolidate everything into one database, perhaps using schemas.
2. Use Azure SQL Managed Instance which supports both cross-database query and Linked Server.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't consolidate.  Each Database is for a diff client's data, and NONE of it is formatted the same... and I don't want to mix data from diff clients.  Sometimes I end up with 10-20 tables for a client, half I use for processing their data.  So, I wouldn't want to try to create a bunch of tables for each client in one database.

Comment: Or replicate the shared data to each database, if it changes rarely.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid replicating the data.  There are several fairly large tables used for reference (ie every city/zip code combination in the us and canada).
I can set up an external data source for the tables, but I think i'll need to copy each funciton/sproc.  Those don't change much, so I am hoping I can do that in a deployment script for when I have the databases created.

Comment: In Azure SQL Database's distributed model, replicating reference data is the _strongly_ preferred method.   The performance cost of distributed query processing usually greatly outweighs the cost of duplicated data.